# XSLT select from a nested element

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here...

I can't select a nested xml element using an XLST transform.

Here is the xml

```
<collection>
<record>
  <leader>01814nam a2200205Ia 4500</leader>
  <controlfield tag="003">PSCA</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="005">20141201150951.0</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="008">131110s9999    xx            000 0 und d</controlfield>
  <datafield tag="040" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">PSCA</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">Calyx</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="110" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="9">76</subfield>
    <subfield code="a">Children's Services Central</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="245" ind1="0" ind2="0">
    <subfield code="a">What's Pedagogy Anyway?</subfield>
    <subfield code="b">Using pedagogical  documentation to engage  with the Early Years Learning  Framework </subfield>
  </datafield>
</record>
</collection
```

I need to select the following data:

/collection

/record

/datafield

-->/@tag='245'

---->/subfield/@code='a'

I would expect the output to be:
"What's Pedagogy Anyway?"

My XLST to select this node/data is as such:

```
<xsl:for-each select="collection/record/datafield">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@tag=245">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/subfeild/@code=a">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/subfeild"/>
                </xsl:when> 
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

I'm running this using the lxml library in Python if that's important.
The code compiles and runs without error. 
My output is null.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change `@code=a` with `@code='a'`, such as:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="collection/record/datafield[@tag=245]/subfield[@code='a']"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT**

If you insist on having a `for-each` loop, see below:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="collection/record/datafield">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@tag=245">
                <xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='a']"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Okay - might have been too soon......how can I iterate over all "datafields" using for-each instead of direct selection?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed

```
<xsl:value-of select="collection/record/datafield[@tag=245]/subfield[@code='a']" />
<xsl:for-each select="collection/record">
    <xsl:value-of select="datafield[@tag=245]/subfield[@code='a']"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I should explain - I need to loop as the XML provided is a fragment of well over 500 complex records. Not this one instance.